# Доступ к папке FileTable для IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, permissions

У меня есть приложение ASP.NET MVC и база данных SqlServer 2014. В базе есть таблица типа FileTable. Я могу обратиться к файлам, хранящимся в таблице, из Windows Explorer по такому пути:

```
\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyData\MyFiles
```

Я хотел бы получить доступ к этим файлам из приложения (например, помещать ссылки на файлы в атрибуты `src` элементов `img`, `video` и `audio`). Я для этого завел виртуальный каталог (назовём его OuterFiles) в моем веб-приложении в IIS. Каталог ссылается на директорию, где хранится содержимое FileTable.  После этого я попытался использовать этот виртуальный каталог в своем приложении. Примерно так:

```html
<img src='/OuterFiles/picture.png' />
```

но изображение не загружается. Вместо этого я получаю ошибку HTTP 500.19:

> **Ошибка конфигурации:**
> Не удалось прочитать файл конфигурации из-за отсутствия необходимых разрешений
>   **Файл конфигурации:**
> \\?\UNC\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyData\MyFiles\web.config

Ради эксперимента я создал другой виртуальный каталог (назовём его AnotherOuterFiles), ссылающийся на обычную папку (например `C:\SomeFolder`), также содержащую изображения, и написал следующую разметку:

```html
<img src='/AnotherOuterFiles/picture2.png' />
```

и это сработало.

Очевидно, Windows (или SqlServer) не дает IIS'у прав на доступ к папке, хранящей содержимое FileTable, и из-за этого я получаю ошибку 500.19.

Можно ли как-то дать этот доступ, и если да, то как?

P.S.

1. Я пытался обратиться к свойствам этой папки, чтобы дать доступ к ней
   определенным пользователям, но в свойствах папки просто нет вкладки
   Безопасность, где можно это назначить
2. Я заходил в SqlServer Configuration Manager и установил там флаг
   *Allow remote clients access to FILESTREAM data*, к сожалению это не помогло
3. Я создал алиас для этой папки с помощью команды mklink командной
   строки, и уже на этот алиас натравил виртуальный каталог, но
   проблема осталась

Comment: @i-one в свойствах инстанса стоит Full access enabled, в свойствах бд Non-Transacted Access выставлен в Full

Comment: @i-one в данном случае они на одной машине находятся. allow remote clients было включено на всякий случай. А как посмотреть от какого аккаунта запущен пул?

Comment: @i-one возможно это, в настройках пула есть свойство Удостоверение. Его значение ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: @i-one логин sql server

Comment: @i-one спасибо за комментарии, буду рад ответу)

Comment: Не могли бы вы информацию из комментариев перенести в вопрос? Так будущим читателям будет легче разобраться в постановке проблемы и в решении.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы читать файлы, загруженные в FileTable, обращаясь к ним через UNC-директорию, нужно дать пользователю (тому, от чьего имени производится чтение) доступ к файловой таблице.

Доступ этот, однако, регулируется не через Windows ACL, задаваемые, в частности, в свойствах директории во вкладке *Security* (*Безопасность*), а средствами SqlServer.

Так, например, если ASP.NET приложение выполняется в IIS в пуле c именем PoolName, то аккаунт этого пула идентифицируется как `IIS APPPOOL\PoolName`.

Соответственно для аккаунта пула в инстансе SqlServer нужно создать Windows-логин:

```sql
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\PoolName] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
```

В базе данных для этого логина нужно создать пользователя БД и дать ему права на чтение файловой таблицы:

```sql
USE [DatabaseName];
GO
CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\PoolName] FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\PoolName];
GO
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[MyFiles] TO [IIS APPPOOL\PoolName];
GO
```

Это для случая, если IIS и SqlServer установлены на одной машине (в этом случае, кстати, включение в конфигураторе флага *Allow remote clients access to FILESTREAM data* не требуется).

Если IIS и SqlServer на разных машинах в домене, то ASP.NET приложение можно поместить в пул, работающий от имени какого-либо пользователя домена, указав в скриптах выше вместо `IIS APPPOOL\PoolName` соответствующий `DOMAIN\UserName`.

Теперь ASP.NET приложение сможет читать файлы, располагающиеся в файловой таблице SqlServer, обращаясь к ним через UNC-путь. Например так:

```cs
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyData\MyFiles\picture.png"))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Что же касается отображения FileTable в виртуальную директорию IIS, то с этим проблема. И она в следующем.

Даже если, как указано выше, соответствующему пулу приложений в IIS дать доступ к FileTable, IIS всё равно не отдаёт файл из виртуальной директории, сопоставленной с файловой таблицей, возвращая при этом ошибку *500.19*.

Анализ ProcessMonitor-ом показывает, что если доступ настроен, то IIS Worker Process вполне себе способен читать файлы из файловой таблицы. В частности, если в файловую таблицу положить файл с именем *web.config*, то ProcessMonitor показывает успешное чтение. Далее IIS может возвратить ошибку о невозможности прочитать *web.config* из-за недостатка прав, но истинная причина не в этом.

Истинная причина, по-видимому, в том, что IIS пытается установить слежение за директорией FileTable и на этом спотыкается:

```
Operation: NotifyChangeDirectory
Result: NOT SUPPORTED
```

поскольку файловые таблицы эту функциональность не поддерживают (см. [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492089.aspx), в разделе *File System Functionality Supported in FileTables*, `Directory change notifications: No`).

Не делай IIS этого, файлы из виртуальной директории, скорее всего, прекрасно бы отдавались.

Слежение за директориями в IIS возможно отключить (см. [KB911272](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/911272)). Для приложений .NET Framework, начиная с версии 4.5, это можно делать через web.config

```xml
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled"/>
```

однако, похоже, что эта настройка влияет на приложение, но не на виртуальные директории.

Есть также глобальная настройка, которая, вроде бы, должна влиять в том числе и на виртуальные директории (я этот вариант не проверял).

В ветке реестра

```text
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET
```

или (для 32-битных приложений на x64 системе)

```text
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET
```

нужно создать параметр `FCNMode` типа *DWORD* и установить его значение в 1 (может потребоваться рестарт системы). Однако это повлияет на все приложения всех сайтов, работающих в IIS, что может быть нежелательно.

Если глобальной настройкой проблема не решится (или она не является подходящим вариантом, т.к. в слежении всё-таки есть своя польза), то альтернативный путь - создать простейший контроллер, который отдавал бы файлы. Что-то наподобие (упрощённо) такого:

```cs
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 1800,
                    Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any,
                    VaryByParam = "fileName")]
    [Route("/images/{fileName}")]
    public ActionResult GetImage(string fileName)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        string dirName = @"\\sql-server-name\mssqlserver\MyData\MyFiles";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(dirName, fileName);

        string contentType = null;
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpeg":
            case ".jpg":
                contentType = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/png";
                break;

                ...

            default:
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                break;
        }

        return File(filePath, contentType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Поправки. Вместо `{fileName}` стоило бы взять `{*filePath}`, а список mime-типов лучше бы не хардкодить, а вытянуть из конфига...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я правильно понимаю `*` - это чтобы отдавались файлы и из вложенных каталогов тоже? Тут вдобавок, наверное, и `Server.MapPath()` сработает, если mklink-ом алиас настраивали.

Comment: Да, это для вложенных каталогов. А про конфиг я фигню сказал, вытащить оттуда список mime-типов - это будет куча кода, размером по-больше оператора switch :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а мне нравится идея тянуть mime-types из конфига, это удобно. Можно на старте приложения загрузить пары в Dictionary, а тут просто к нему обращаться. Пусть, впрочем, доработки и определение целесообразности останутся на усмотрение применяющего.

Comment: @i-one большое спасибо, буду пробовать!