# Роутинг изображений в asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, маршрутизация

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая проблема. Имеется приложение asp.net mvc. Наподобие википедии. В нем есть статьи, в статьях могут содержаться изображения. Изначально изображения хранились в файловой системе в папке внутри веб-приложения. Затем потребовалось перенести изображения из файловой системы в базу данных, что в итоге было сделано (воспользовался ответом [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627570/196379)). Но тут возникла проблема. Дело в том, что в статьях содержатся ссылки на изображения в файловой системе, но так как теперь изображения переехали в бд, то ссылки стали недействительными. Теперь я получаю изображения не по пути наподобие 
`<img src="/ImagesFolder/myImg.png" />` а примерно так: `<img src="Images/GetFile?id=myImg.png" />` где `Images/GetFile` - это действие контроллера, которое обращается к бд за запрошенным файлом. 
Разумеется я не хотел бы переписывать тысячи статей чтобы в каждой из них править ссылку на изображения (хотя теоретически это можно сделать). Хотелось бы как-то настроить маршрутизацию в приложении, чтобы оно знало, что старый url вида `ImagesFolder/myImg.png` надо сопоставить новому вида `Images/GetFile?id=myImg.png`. Может быть кто-то знает как это сделать для файлов в asp.net mvc? Пробовал разные варианты, например появившуюся наастройку маршрутов с помощью атрибутов, но ничего не вышло(

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет этот пост:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21205212/5665527

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Legacy images",
    url: "ImagesFolder/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller="Images", 
        action="GetFile"
    });

//...

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index"
    });
```

Comment: я думаю получите 404

Comment: @tCode А так?.)

Comment: @free_ze к сожалению 404(